# Mean value theorem and continuity of derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Suppose $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is differentiable in $(-h,h)$. By the mean value theorem $$f(h)-f(0)=f'(\tilde h)h$$ for $0<\tilde h<|h|$. Now, for $h\neq 0$, we can write $$\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=f'(\tilde h)$$ Since $\tilde h\rightarrow 0$ when $h\rightarrow 0$, we take the limit one each side to find $$f'(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{\tilde h\rightarrow 0}f'(\tilde h)$$ but this would seem to imply that $f'$ is continuous which we know it is not always true: $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ being the counterexample. So what is wrong with my logic?

Comment: Julian. Wrote a comment https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876974/where-is-the-error-in-my-proof-that-all-derivatives-are-continuous?rq=1 Your thoughts?

Comment: You can say that $\lim_{h\to 0}f'(\tilde h) =f'(0)$ but you can't say that $\lim_{\tilde h\to 0}f'(\tilde h) =f'(0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to take the limit you have to show first that it exists ($\lim_{\tilde h\rightarrow 0}f'(\tilde h)=f'(0)$ is true iff $f'$ is continuous at $0$).

Comment: What confuses me is the following: take $h=1/n$. Then the left hand side $n(f(1/n)-f(0))$ is a sequence of numbers that converges to $f'(0)$. On the right hand side we have a sequence $f'(\tilde h)$ which is identical term by term to the sequence $n(f(1/n)-f(0))$. How can one converge and the other one not converge?

Comment: I'm confused: if $f'(0)$ exists, doesn't his mean that $(f(h)-f(0))/h$ converges to $f'(0)$ for any sequence $h\rightarrow 0$?. I am taking the sequence $1/n$.

Comment: I understand your point. Here is the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876974/where-is-the-error-in-my-proof-that-all-derivatives-are-continuous?rq=1

Comment: @julian.marr You are right, it does. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Consider a sequence $h_n$ that coverges to $h$. Corresponding to each $h_n$ we have an $\tilde h_n$ and a $f'(\tilde h_n)$. It seems to me that the sequence $\left\{f'(\tilde h_n)\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $f'(0)$, which does not imply that $f'$ is continuous, just that that particular sequence is convergent.